# Is it possible to Convert php database information to this format json file?

Tags: php, json

Is it possible to Convert php database information to this format json file??

About php Database Information

```
INSERT INTO `Peter` (`Name`, `Age`) VALUES ('Peter', '16');
```

Is it possible to json_encode to Convert php database information to the following format json file

Json File

`[['Name','Peter'],['Age','16']]`

NOT
`[{
    "Name": "Alberta",
    "Age": "16"
  }]`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Everything is possible. Since you are getting:

```
[{
    "name": "Alberta",
    "Age": "16"
  }]
```

then I assume that you somehow load the data like this from your database (pseudocode):

```
$arrayOfResults = [];
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $arrayOfResults[] = $row;
}
```

or maybe more explicit:

```
$arrayOfResults = [];
while($row = $dbStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $arrayOfResults[] = [
       'name' => $row['name'];
       'Age' => $row['Age'];
   ];
}
```

Right?

Simply instead of adding the actual row add an array with db record's values where each element is an array itself:

```
$arrayOfResults = [];
while($row = $dbStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $arrayOfResults[] = [
       [ 'Name', $row['name'] ], 
       [ 'Age', $row['age'] ]
   ];
}
```

Just a comment: generally if you want a format like that then you probably have something wrong in the code which is meant to read that file as you should not rely on on the order of elements in each row. In fact for your needs actually key => value format was established in the first place.